# Can chart.js order a bar chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

In my project, I have some bar graphs and I want to give the user an option to ordenate them in ascending or descending, I know that I can do this by code but I want to know if chart.js has a functionality to help me with that.

Comment: Yes you can do it.

Comment: with chartjs?? How?